# VueJs @error for handling broken links in images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, onerror

I am facing a weird problem with vueJs @error handler, what I want to
do is to hide the images with broken links, and display a placeholder instead, but if I have for examples two images and both of them have a broken links, only the first image of the broken link is displaying the placeholder, while the other image with a broken link is just displaying, the browser's broken image default logo

here's the code I did for testing, I know this is not a proper way of writing the code in Vue, but it was for testing purposes

```
  <div id="app">
    <img width="25%" id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Wallpaper-img_0254.jpg" @error="handle()">
    <img width="25%" id="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" @error="handle()">
    <img v-show="ifImageBroken" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <p>{{brokenText}}</p>
    <HelloWorld/>
  </div>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data () {
    return {
      ifImageBroken: false,
      brokenText: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  methods: {
    handle : function() {
     document.getElementById('img').style.display = 'none'
     this.ifImageBroken = true;
     this.brokenText = 'unable to load image'
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I just wanted to know, if this `@error` directive can handle multiple cases of broken images

Comment: I think the problem may be that you have 2 `img` elements with the same `id` value. Standard HTML doesn't allow this since id's need to be unique. If you have multiple elements with the same `id`, only (I believe) the first will work with the `getElementById`

Answer (score 6):

I face the same problem and I use `object` to solve it because @error depend on broken links but not broken images inside links, so I create something to switch between them

```
<object data="https://here the right image if not found will display the image inside img tag.jpg" type="image/png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Not found image">
</object>
```

In the first one will check if `:data` in `object` found or not, if not found he will switch to `<img>` tag and here you will put your placeholder image,

Update 2:
I use your code and update it, I hope it work

```
  <div id="app">
    <img width="25%" id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Wallpaper-img_0254.jpg" @error="imgPlaceholder">

    <img width="25%" id="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" @error="imgPlaceholder">
    <p>{{brokenText}}</p>
    <HelloWorld/>
  </div>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data () {
    return {
      ifImageBroken: false,
      brokenText: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  methods: {
    imgPlaceholder(e) {
        e.target.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/300"
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here I create a new method that takes an event and change current broken URL image with another one

Comment: yup if it dynamic, but if it normal url with https you will use data="", if dynamic url you will use :data=""

Comment: I've updated the answer, in `data="here right image link"`, and if right image link is broken he will display the image inside `<img src="here the not found image placeholder" >`

Comment: hmmm, but you're not using @error at all, do you think that this can still work with @error, I mean can it work with v-show to hide or show the placeholder, but still keeping in the `<object>` tag

Comment: I'm not using @error in this case because he does not catch the broken images, but catch the broken URLs, so if you have field loading in image so `<object>` will replace it by another image, but @error will not catch something like that, and yes you can use it with v-show

Comment: So you can add more than one not found image and add `v-if` conditions to control it without @error handler

Comment: what do you mean it does not catch broken images, it's the URL that should be broken not the Image, what I meant with my question is to check if multiple images have broken URL's and how to replace all of them